# Javascript .accordion() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am having an issue with my javascript on my website:
My `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave()` have been solved, thanks to your help, however my `.accordion()` is still not working. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
HTML:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!--Accordion is not working, mouseenter is only working in first product, header is not all the way to the left-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/carousel.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shopping.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"                                                      href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <h4><mark>Student Project #5 H.B.</mark></h4></br>
    <h2>Premium Computer Supplies!</h2>
</header>
<body>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="row" id="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img src="surface3.jpg" alt="Microsoft Surface">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <div class="accordion">
            <h4>Microsoft Surface Pro 3</h4>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Insert description for the product here</p>
                    <p>Starting at $999!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="row" id="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img src="surface3cover.jpg" alt="Microsoft Surface Type Cover">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <div id="accordion">
            <h4>Microsoft Surface Pro 3 Typer Cover</h4>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Insert description for the product here</p>
                    <p>Starting at $129!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="row" id="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img src="mabook.jpg" alt="Apple Macbook Pro Retina">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <div id="accordion">
            <h4>Macbook Pro Retina Display</h4>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Insert description for the product here</p>
                    <p>Starting at $999!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="row" id="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img src="superdrive.jpg" alt="Apple SurperDrive">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <div id="accordion">
            <h4>Apple SuperDrive</h4>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Insert description for the product here</p>
                    <p>Starting at $79!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div class="row" id="row">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img src="case1.jpg" alt="Laptop Case">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <div id="accordion">
            <h4>Laptop Case</h4>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Insert description for the product here</p>
                    <p>Starting at $39!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
  });

    $( ".row" ).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ fontSize : 14 });
});

    $( ".row" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ fontSize : 13 });
});
    </script>
</body>

CSS:

    img {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
header{
    background-color: crimson;
    color:darkblue;
    padding-left: 0;/*why is this not working*/
    width:100%
}
body{
    width:80%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 13;
    padding-left: 5%
}
#row{
    background-color: white;
    width:30%;
    padding-left: 5%;
```

}

Comment: In your css, put a space between `padding-left:` and `0`

Comment: Because each id must be unique, jquery only grabs the first one. You should add a class to them all and reference that instead.

Comment: `id`s must be unique within the document.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 when Javascript just stops working, you have an invalid DOM.  Ensure your tags open and close evenly, you have unique ID, etc.

Comment: thank you, I added this space and the padding stayed the same?

Comment: The whitespace doesn't matter.

Comment: @StaticVoid wouldn't <div class="row"> be the class I need? how do I reference that in my javascript?

Comment: as `$('.row')`, not `$('#row')`

Comment: @hbteibet my mistake. In this case the whitespace in your css doesn't matter. There are some cases where it does. The problem is probably a margin or padding on the h2 and h4 tags.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple elements can not have the same `ID`. Then it wouldn't be *identifying*, now would it?

Use a class selector on those accordions and rows, otherwise it will only find the first.

Answer (score 3):

Ids must be unique, as you already have common class `row` added bind event using it. use class selector to select all elements with class

```
$(".row").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({ fontSize : 14 });
});
$(".row").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({ fontSize : 13 });
});
```

also use common class with accordion, So use

```
<div class="accordion">
```

instead of

```
<div id="accordion">
```

Then you can use

```
$(".accordion").accordion()
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped with all but the accordion function. I changed the code to <div class="accordion"> and the javascript to .accordion, however the accordion style is not activating. Any ideas?

Comment: @hbteibet, Sorry mate no idea

Comment: thanks anyway, your previous code helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Element ids must be unique.  Use classes instead.

```
<div class="accordion">...
```

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion();
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is you are binding events to div ids. You should bind events to class.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>

<script>
    $( ".row" ).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ fontSize : 14 });
});
    </script>

<script>
    $( ".row" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ fontSize : 13 });
});
    </script>
```

You need to add according class. Also, consider putting your all javascripts under single script tag.